# Eclipse: change name of existing package with classes inside

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, is it possible to change name of the package if it has name `(default package)` and has classes inside it?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In the version of Eclipse I'm using (Indigo service release 1), the "Rename" option doesn't come up for the default package (unlike other packages) - but if you select all the classes then right-click and select "Move" that will let you put them in a new package.

(As far as I can tell, the Rename option is for renaming classes *without* changing their package, but Move certainly works for moving *between* packages.)

Screenshots of the process:

**Original situation**

[image: Before]

**Select all classes and show the Refactor part of the context menu**

[image]

**Select "Move", click on Create Package and type in a name (mypackage in this case)**

[image: Move dialog]

**The final result**

[image: After]

Alternatively, if you want to move them to an existing package, you could just drag and drop the classes.

For those suggesting Refactor -> Rename on the package, here's a screenshot showing that *not* working on my machine:

[image: No Rename option]

Comment: I just realized that "for the default package" is key here: for all other packages, there's the "Rename" option, but not the default one.

Comment: @Kjir: Hence the "unlike other packages" part of my answer.

Comment: To be exact: Right Click > Refractor > Move  or Rename. Seems to work

Comment: @RCola: For the default package? Doesn't work on my build. Will edit my version number into my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

Either just right-click the class and choose Refactor->Rename, or insert the appropriate `package foo.bar` at the top and use Ctrl-1 to quickfix.

Answer (score 1):

Create a New package inside the SRC folder and then drag your class file into the New package.So that the default package name getting changed

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to go into your src folder in the relevant project folder in your workspace and there, create a new folder. Name that folder as whatever package name you want and put all your .java files into that folder. Refresh eclipse, close the .java files and open from the new location.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new package under 'Java Package' with the desired name. Then dragged and dropped the source files from default. IDE would ask  to refactor; then proceed with it. 
Default package disappeared and source files updated.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Create a new package in the same project

Step 2. Click hold and drop the classes from the default package to new package