# change package name back to (default package)?

Tags: java, eclipse, package-name

In Eclipse, After importing a project, the packages and subpackages somehow became renamed.

for example:

Original project package naming before import:

```
(default package)
foo.bar.dog
foo.bar.cat
foo.bar.horse
```

After Import:

```
net
net.foo.bar.dog
net.foo.bar.cat
net.foo.bar.horse
```

Right Click -> Refactor doesnt work. This issue is messing up the imports in all of my classes and it seems to much of a hassle to change the imports in 250+ classes.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this similar issue, I tried one of the steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161840/eclipse-change-name-of-existing-package-with-classes-inside) and it worked.

What I did was expand the package so you can see the files listed underneath.  Select the files, **right-click->refactor->move** (I know you said refactor didn't work, but perhaps you were clicking on the package name, and not the files within?).  There should be a (default package) you can move the files to in the pop-up window.