# Change package name in Eclipse

Tags: java, package

I need to change the package to Eclipse.

Now my package looks like this:

```
test
    java
        helloword
```

But I want to change it on it:

```
java
    helloword
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This has already been answered in the past:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10161882/2350479

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse: change name of existing package with classes inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161840/eclipse-change-name-of-existing-package-with-classes-inside)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple:

1. Select the package you want to change
2. Press F2
3. Enter the new package name

Comment: Are you sure F2 worked in eclipse ? As I know F2 worked in Netbeans, but not sure with Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the package you want to rename.
2. Select Refactor.
3. Click on rename
4. Type new name.
   There u go...